# Ways to host a small site on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: web-hosting

I've written a small site that employees will be using for time entry and things of that nature and I need a way to host it on my server which is running Windows Server 2008 Standard. I'm using mostly PHP and Javascript on the site but nothing very intensive.

I've heard of using XAMPP as a way to host, but I'd like to hear some more options before I settle on something. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install PHP for IIS7, which is perhaps better integrated with the rest of the Server 2008 ecosystem, and pretty straightforward to administer.

Comment: I agree with Adrien. Since you have Windows server, you should use IIS.